# Suppress updating of a child components that are connected to redux state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, react-redux

I am making an app using react and redux. I want to stop child components from updating in the parent component, even though they are connected to state independently. `shouldComponentUpdate` does not prevent this. Is there some way this is possible? Maybe like caching a pre-rendered version of the children? I don't need it to be interactive at all, not even scrolling is required. I just need it to be visually the same.

Code example:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { dontReload: false }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SomeStateConnectedComponent />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How could I make it so the state connected component does not update if `dontReload` is true?

Comment: Why wouldn't `shouldComponentUpdate` not work here?  If you're using redux then presumably you're using `mapStateToProps`, so that prop equality (or whatever logic you wanna use) check should be totally fine.

Comment: Hey @user5505266 Feel free to let me know if my answer misunderstood something or if you want to clarify your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you export the non-connected Component that `<SomeStateConnectedComponent />` is based on, then pass some fake props (including callbacks like `() => {}`) to that, and use that instead of the connected version? This should create and display a non-updating version of that component.

Because it sounds like you would otherwise be forced to change the code inside `<SomeStateConnectedComponent />` (at the very least pass some extra props to it)  just for this (it seems) pretty niche use-case.

**Edit**: for use with state.dontReload you could do a conditional render, something like like

```
return this.state.dontReload ?       
     <NonConnectedComponent fakeProp={42} /> :
      <SomeStateConnectedComponent />
```